# sort command in linux first sort special characters, than lower case and uppercase.

Tags: linux, sorting

I am using sort command for sorting in file.My data contains as follows.

```
abc.com
*.abc.com
abcd.com
ABC.com
```

I am using following sort command for sorting

```
sort -f -V filename
```

And It is giving me following result.

```
abc.com
ABC.com
abcd.com
*.abc.com
```

But I want following result

```
*.abc.com
abc.com
ABC.com
abcd.com
```

So I want that * should come first like mentioned above in my expected result.

I have tried various options in sort command but not successful.So Is there any option in sort command where I can get the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
sort -f -k1 filename
```

Comment: `-f, --ignore-case`
    fold lower case to upper case characters

Comment: `-k, --key=KEYDEF`
    sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type